# Как реализовать запрос с использованием PHP SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

```
// Получаю экземпляр SoapClient
$url = "";
$client = new SoapClient($url, ["trace" => 1, "exception" => 0]); 
// Получаю список доступных SOAP-функций
$client->__getFunctions();
```

`SoapClient::__getFunctions` возвращает следующее:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(44) "GetDataResponse GetData(GetData $parameters)"
  [1]=>
  string(44) "GetDataResponse GetData(GetData $parameters)"
}
```

Далее:

```
// Вызываю SOAP-функцию
$client->GetData($params);
// Возвращаю SOAP-ответ
$client->__getLastResponse();
```

SOAP-ответ приходит в виде вложенного XML документа. То есть придется парсить XML содержимое `__last_response`? Я правильно это делаю?

Если я не указываю при получении экземпляра SoapClient `$options = ['trace' => 1, 'exception' => 0]`, то не получаю `__last_response`. Вместо этого я получаю указанное ниже. Почему?

```
object(SoapClient)#82 (5) {
  ["_soap_version"]=>
  int(1)
  ["sdl"]=>
  resource(5) of type (SOAP SDL)
  ["httpsocket"]=>
  resource(6) of type (stream)
  ["_use_proxy"]=>
  int(0)
  ["httpurl"]=>
  resource(7) of type (SOAP URL)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать данные, полученные в качестве результата вызова SOAP-функции:

```
$result = $client->GetData($params);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я это понимал, но пришлось использовать __last_response, так как не знал о том, что нужно применить `htmlspecialchars()` для `$result`.